# ASP .NET User Control Properties not getting displayed in property window

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I created a user control with a few properties. In my demo project, the properties that have been exposed using getter and setter methods are being correctly displayed in the property window.
[image: PropertiesWindow]
This is how I expected it to work.

When I copied the files related to the user control to my main solution, I no longer see the properties in the properties window. The control now displays as an HTML Element instead of the actual name of the control.

[image: MissingProperties]

Comment: so when you drag + drop the user control from the project explore into the web page, does it also put at the top the markup to register the control? Try the drag  + drop onto the web page - see if that helps.

Comment: The control is registered in the web.config file in case of both the DEMO project as well as the real one.

Comment: Well, it takes 10 seconds to try my suggesting. I mean, maybe the tags or markup is messed up in the config - so at least try registering on the give page. If that works, then you can look for a say a missing end tag in the config file. On the other had, if it don't work by registering on a given page, then the setting in the config file will never work either!!! - this is called basic troubleshooting skills - you should thus try such suggestions. this is how you approach problem solving, be it computers, or the process of making a cup of coffee in the morning.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. I did try out your suggestion on a brand new project as well as my main application. It still shows up as an HTML element in both cases.